# find out aif document service components

Tags: service, document, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aif

I'm in an AX 2012 R2 environment.

I've a custom document service in our environment. I can see it by opening the AIFService form in the AOT. There may be a better way of browsing all the available document services. I haven't found it yet.

Anyway, how do I find out all the parts (query, document name, document class name) associated with this custom service, assuming the standard naming conventions haven't been followed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To know what document services are available, go to the **AOT** - **Classes** - **AIFDocumentService**. Right click the class, then **Add-Ins** - **Type hierarchy browser**. You'll get a list of all document service classes.

To find the document class based on the service, just open the source code of the service and look at the code. The `create` method for example takes a parameter of the type of the document and the `find` methods returns an object of that type.

In the document class declaration you will find a marco. The name of that macro (minus DCT) will be the name of your query. The AxBC classes will be `Ax` + the name of the table, for example `AxInventTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
AxdWizardParameters     axdWizardParameters;
;

axdWizardParameters = AifServiceClassGenerator::getServiceParameters(classStr(YOURSERVICECLASSNAME));

info(axdWizardParameters.parmAifServiceClassName());
info(axdWizardParameters.parmAifEntityClassName());
info(axdWizardParameters.parmName());
info(axdWizardParameters.parmQueryName());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you explain why and how this helps with the OPs problem?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! OP have a custom document service in his environment and he looking how to find out all the parts (query, document name, document class name) associated with this custom service.

Comment: If he run the Job from my post the output will be: parmQueryName() - the name of query used, parmAifEntityClassName() - document name, parmName() - document class name