# AIF salesOrders Default fields uncheck

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I have one quastion. do anyone know how I can remove a default checked field?
In this case the field name is 'Value' and exist in SalesTable as DefaultDimension. The field in Salestable is not mandatory and in AxSalesTable class I added into (just in case) initMandatoryFieldsExemptionList() as well as I unchecked from the Table 'AifDataPolicy' which stored the flag  but in the grid is still checked and disable as control.
[image: XML Values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property 'Fields\Dynamic' on your SalesTable datasourse to 'No' and delete field `DefaultDimension` from field list. After that refresh your service.

Comment: Please follow this link if you need to find the query which your service is used http://stackoverflow.com/a/38311406/6575455